# Render Application Layout in Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forem

I'm using the Forem engine and have a `_header.html.erb` partial in my main application. How would I render this partial in Forem's view?

I'd rather not duplicate the code in the view.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with Forem, but can't you add an .erb extension to the forem view and then render the partial as usual?

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
```